# Explanation of Mysql date_format documentation

Tags: mysql, escaping, date-format

in the mysql documentation for date_format (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
it has the specifiers in the *format* string...
All of them make sense, although some seem odd or rarely used.

Until you get to the last one.
"%x" which is defined as "x, for any 'x' not listed above"

What does this mean?

if my date has a random character in it, like "07-28-1973z 11:15:22", why wouldn't my *format* string be "%m-%d-%Yz %T" ?  do I have to escape the z?

What value is %x?

Any thoughts appreciated.